# Pi Number Calculation gives 3.22

Tags: java, pi

I'm trying to calculate pi number using this formula:
pi/4 = 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 ...

```
   public class Calculator
{
  double process=1;
  double piValue=0;
  int approximation;
  double value;
  public Calculator( int precision)
  {
    approximation = precision;
  }

  public void calculate()
  {
    while(process<=approximation)
    {
      value = 1/(process+2);
      if(process%2==0)
      {
        value = value;
      }
      else
      {
        value = value * (-1);
      }
      piValue = piValue + value;
      process++;
    }
    System.out.println((1+piValue)*4.0);

  }
}
```

I see nothing wrong here but i keep getting very meaningless outputs. Here are some examples:

```
23. step: 3.1490100018286853 This is OK.
1501. step: 3.22874239242146
100,000 step: 3.2274312772602247
```

So its limit while "step number" goes to infinity is around 3.22 . How can i fix this problem?

I have just started studying Java, please keep in mind that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you divide by 1, 3, 5, 7... it should be `1/(process * 2 - 1)`, not `1/(process + 2)`

Comment: What is the idea behind this ***if(process%2==0)
      {
        value = value;***   ???

Comment: @Auberon `process` is incremented once, not twice inside the loop.

Comment: @Auberon clarity? are you kidding?

Comment: @Xoce웃Пepeúpa  To decide whether the step is even or odd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When calculating `value` at the top of the `while` loop, your use of `process` is incorrect; you'll wind up calculating -1/3 + 1/4 - 1/5 + ....

Instead of

```
value = 1/(process+2);
```

try

```
value = 1/(2*process + 1);
```

Now this will advance the denominator by odd numbers starting with `3`, which is ok because you're adding `1` at the very end.

With this change and 1,501 loops, I get `3.1409268747021875` -- pretty close for this method of calculating pi.  (100,000 loops prints `3.141602653489781`.)